# Pattern extraction using SED or AWK

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I extract `68` from `v1+r0.68`?

Comment: The fundamental problem with this question is that you have given us no idea of what the *general* form of the input is nor what defines the desired output. With only a single case to work with `{print "68"}` is a valid solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk, returns everything after the last '.'

```
echo "v1+r0.68" | awk -F. '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed to get the number after the last dot:

```
echo 'v1+r0.68' | sed 's/.*[.]\([0-9][0-9]*\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: Why not use a character class?  `s/.+\.(\d)+$/\1/`

Comment: When you do that people down vote you because it is GNU-sed specific

Comment: Thanks a lot...that works like a charm......any sed website of books I can use as a reference.....thanks for the help again.

Comment: @user1886941, this is very good: http://www.cs.ucy.ac.cy/~dzeina/courses/epl371/lectures/06-sed.pdf

Comment: `sed 's/.*\./'` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

grep is good at extracting things:

```
kent$  echo " v1+r0.68"|grep -oE "[0-9]+$" 
68
```

Answer (score 1):

Match the digit string before the end of the line using `grep`:

```
$ echo 'v1+r0.68' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'
68
```

Or match any digits after a `.`

```
$ echo 'v1+r0.68' | grep -Po '(?<=\.)\d+'
68
```

Print everything after the `.` with `awk`:

```
echo "v1+r0.68" | awk -F. '{print $NF}'
68
```

Substitute everything before the `.` with `sed`:

```
echo "v1+r0.68" | sed 's/.*\.//'
68
```

Answer (score 0):

type `man grep`

and you will see

...

```
   -o, --only-matching

          Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

then type `echo 'v1+r0.68' | grep -o '68'`

if you want it any where special do:

```
echo 'v1+r0.68' | grep -o '68' > anyWhereSpecial.file_ending
```